# Regex issue, restricting '*' character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text area, where I am allowing only a-z characters and number, with some special characters (like `(, ), \, _`). My regex looks like:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9()-\/\\_ ]/g
```

and my javascript method is:

```
function checkValue(eleValue)
{
var checked = false ;
    if (eleValue.search(/[^a-zA-Z0-9()-\/\\_ ]/g) != -1)
             checked = true;
    return checked;
}
```

This regex allows '*' in the value, whereas, I want to restrict it.

Please let me know how to do it in regex.

Comment: What do you mean by `restrict` exactly? If you don't want it at all, just put it in the character class?

Comment: How about `/^[a-z0-9()\-\/\\_ ]+$/i`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `-` in the regexp:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9()\-\/\\_ ]/
```

Otherwise, you're matching all the characters between `)` and `/`: `*` `+` `,` `-` `.`

See the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see what characters are in a range.

Comment: Thanks a lot. +1 for giving the reason as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this `regex` to to include `*` also in your search:

`[^a-zA-Z0-9()\-\/\\_ ]{0,1}[*]`

Comment: OP wants to *exclude* `*`

Comment: He is using `^` in his expression. So he is checking to see if characters other than what is mentioned in `[^a-zA-Z0-9()\-\/\\_ ]` are present. `*` is being ignored from the match so he needs to explicitly mention the matching of `*`.

Comment: @Aashray he is checking for any character besides the allowed.. so the `*` should not be in there..

Comment: He's checking to see if anything other than what is mentioned is present in the string. `*` was being ignored but that was because of `-` not being escaped, but anyway, if it did match `*`, then it was wrong and wouldn't have gone into the `if`. So the explicit `*` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkValue (eleValue) {
    var re = new RegExp(/[a-z0-9\(\)\/\\_\s]+/ig);
    return re.test(eleValue);
}
```