# php preg_match multiple patterns

Tags: php, regex

I need to find a string like this @[0000:0000:Username] in a text.

Then I need to extract the first number sequence (user-id) and the Username.
Then I need to replace them with a link.

I'm able to extract the first number sequence but the Username is variable. It can have multiple words (and spaces) but it can also be a single word e.g "John", "John Doe", "John Doe Junior".

The Username can contain alphanumeric characters, periods, underscores and dashes.

This is what I have now with username up to 4 words:

```
/@\[(\d*):\d*:(\S*|\S*\s*\S*\s*\S*\s*\S*)\]/
```

And this is the link I'd like to create:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/user-id/" target="_blank">Username</a>
```

I'm trying to it like this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/$1/" target="_blank">$2</a>
```

This works fine if only one match is found. As soon as there's more matches it messes up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AmalMurali It won't allow more than 4 words in the username.

Comment: @Barmar: Well, the OP says `Obviously this doesn't work.`. It *does* (for the examples shown in the question anyway). I think the question could be improved by explaining all your requirements, @Ziggy.

Comment: He said "with username up to 4 words". That's his way of describing the unwanted limitation.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
/@\[(\d+):\d+:([^\]]+)\]/
```

[^]] searches for all characters that are not ], so basically everything up to the final ]

Comment: The second capture should be the username, not the second number.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/@\[(\d*):\d*:([\w. \-]*)\]/m
```

`[\w. \-]` matches a letter, number, underscore, period, space, and dash. `*` after it allows any number of these.

Comment: yes, you do need to escape `-`. It's the range operator, as in `A-Z`.

Comment: His original regexp says `\d*`. Since that wasn't the part he's having a problem with, I assumed it's what he wants.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758841/regex-issue-restricting-character/20758890#20758890 for what happens if you forget to escape `-`.

Comment: That's true. But since I didn't put it there, I needed to escape it. This is a simpler, safer, more general way to do it.

Comment: no need to escape `-` at the beginning or at the end of character class.

Comment: Argh, there was a whole back-and-forth with Amal Murali about that. He's deleted his side of the conversation.

Comment: Yes, I just stated there is no force to escape it at your regex

Comment: I didn't even realize I had it last. Like I said, it's safer and more general to escape, you don't have to worry about where it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
@\[(\d+):\d+:([-\w. ]+)\]
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/fI9eD5)

Comment: And this one too. Thanks folks!